# Use of Linear Color mapper in Bokeh

Tags: python, visualization, bokeh, graph-visualization

I am intending to create a scatter plot with a linear colormapper. The dataset is the popular Female Literacy and Birthrate dataset.

The plot would have the "GDP per capita" on the x axis and "Life Expectancy at Birth" on the y axis. In addition to this (and this is where i am running into the issue), is to vary the color of the points according to "Birth rate".

Current Code:

```
#DATA MANIPULATION

# import Pandas, Bokeh, etc
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.io import show, output_file
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.palettes import Viridis256 as palette
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.sampledata.autompg import autompg as df
from bokeh.transform import linear_cmap

# load the data file

excel_file = '../factbook.xlsx'
#(removed url above since it is private)
factbook  = pd.read_excel(excel_file)


source = ColumnDataSource(factbook)

colormapper = linear_cmap(field_name = factbook["Birth rate"], palette=palette, low=min(factbook["Birth rate"]), high=max(factbook["Birth rate"]))


p = figure(title = "UN Factbook Bubble Visualization", 
           x_axis_label = 'GDP per capita', y_axis_label = 'Life expectancy at birth')

p.circle(x = 'GDP per capita', y = 'Life expectancy at birth', source = source, color =colormapper)

output_file("file", title="Bubble Graph")

show(p)
```

---

the p.circle line is having an issue with consuming the colormapper. I would like help on understanding how to resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

The `field_name` parameter should be provided with the *name of a column*. You are supplying the entire data column itself. Since you have not provided a complete runnable example, it is impossible to test for sure, but presumably you want:

```
linear_cmap(field_name="Birth rate", ...)
```